# Why should I implement "impl Encoder for &OpaqueHolder"?

Tags: rust

If I have `impl X` for `Y` and `impl<T: X> X` for `&T`, why would I still need `impl X` for `&Y`? And why do I only see this when using it in a tuple? What am I missing?

```
pub struct OpaqueHolder(str);

impl OpaqueHolder {
    fn from_borrowed(s: &str) -> &Self {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(s) }
    }
    
    fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn make_opaque() -> &'static OpaqueHolder {
    &OpaqueHolder::from_borrowed("OpaqueHolder")
}


trait Encoder {
    fn as_encoded_string(&self) -> String;

    fn encode(&self) -> String {
        self.as_encoded_string()
    }
}

impl Encoder for OpaqueHolder {
    fn as_encoded_string(&self) -> String {
        return self.as_str().to_string()
    }
}

impl<T: Encoder> Encoder for &T {
    fn as_encoded_string(&self) -> String {
        (&**self).as_encoded_string()
    }
}

// THIS SHOULDNT BE NECESSARY< BUT FOR SOME REASON IS... WHY?
impl Encoder for &OpaqueHolder {
    fn as_encoded_string(&self) -> String {
        return self.as_str().to_string()
    }
}


impl<A: Encoder, B: Encoder> Encoder for (A, B) {
    fn as_encoded_string(&self) -> String {
        [
            self.0.as_encoded_string(),
            self.1.as_encoded_string(),
        ].concat()
    }
}


fn main() {
    // this works w/o the specific &OpaqueHolder
    println!("{:}", make_opaque().encode());
    // only shows up on the tuple
    println!("{:}", (make_opaque(), make_opaque()).encode());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

- `OpaqueHolder` is an *unsized type* since it only wraps `str`, which is an unsized type. A `str` represents some utf8-encoded sequence of bytes, but that sequence can be of any length.
- Any generic type parameter like `impl<T: Encoder> Encoder for &T` has an implicit `T: Sized` constraint. [`Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html) is a marker trait auto-implemented by the compiler on types that have a known size at compile-time.

So your generic implementation on `&T` doesn't work for `&OpaqueHolder` because `OpaqueHolder` isn't `Sized`.

---

To fix it, you can relax the implied `Sized` bound by using `?Sized`:

```
impl<T: Encoder + ?Sized> Encoder for &T {
             // ^^^^^^^^
    fn as_encoded_string(&self) -> String {
        (&**self).as_encoded_string()
    }
}
```

And now it will work without needing the additional implementation ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5ca2ada79c298fab0d5e16fa4131430e)).

Comment: Thanks, I trust you this is the solution, definitely need more time to understand it.